# how to transform string to long and doubele using JoltTransformation in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I have some problem with using NIFI and JoltTransformation. I have two string fields in my json:
"checkpay" : "2345,89"
"id" : "45789098"
I need to transform this field to ineteger and double using JoltTransformation.
I tried something like that:

```
    {
     "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
           "*": {
             "isUnderAge": "=toBoolean",
             "checkPay": "=toDouble",
             "id": "=toLong"
               }
             }
           }
```

] but is working only for boolean value. Maybe someone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately the input is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Please try using https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception to see if your code works